# Selectively Split Python String by Position

Tags: python, string, split

I have a string that I've split almost to the level of what I need but not completely. My string looks like this to start:

str1 =

```
Out[135]: 'C:\\\\Users\\\\U321103\\\\OneDrive - IBERDROLA S.A\\VARIABILIDAD CLIMATICA\\\\VORTEX\\\\WIND8\\349039.SPAIN.ESTE.CARRASCOSA.Power.csv'
```

I have used a split technique to get it to here:

```
str2 = str1.split('WIND8\\')[1].split('.csv')[0]

Out[132]: '349039.SPAIN.ESTE.CARRASCOSA.Power'
```

However, I really need this final answer:

str3 = SPAIN.ESTE.Power

And, I'm not sure how to remove the string content before "SPAIN" and between "ESTE" and ".Power". The word "ESTE" will change - meaning that "ESTE" is a region of a country and will change each time the script is run. In the str1 variable, these subset strings will change each time the script is run: "349039", "SPAIN", "ESTE", "CARRASCOSA" so I think that the code needs to select by position between the periods "." in str2. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you split that output again using `.` as separator and then concatenate the last three strings in the format you need ?

Comment: Split one more time and re-join based on index.

Comment: Does the file always follow the '{NUMBER}.{COUNTRY}.{REGION}.{WORD}.Power.csv'? Let me know, because it that's the case a better strategy may be to use regex and match groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As McLovin said in a comment, you should be able to split by `.` and then rejoin by index, assuming that the structure remains the same.

```
COUNTRY, REGION, UTILITY = 1, 2, -1
str2 = '349039.SPAIN.ESTE.CARRASCOSA.Power'
substrs = str2.split('.')
str3 = '.'.join([substrs[i] for i in [COUNTRY, REGION, UTILITY]])
str3
>> 'SPAIN.ESTE.Power'
```

For more complicated / flexible splitting and parsing, consider using regular expressions with the `re` module. There is a bit of a learning curve but they're very useful and there are lots of tutorials out there.

Edited to match the suggestion by joseville

Comment: Would suggest `1`, `2` and `-1` be named variables/constants for readability.


`COUNTRY, REGION, UTILITY = 1, 2, -1`
`str3 = '.'.join(fields[tag] for tag in (COUNTRY, REGION, UTILITY))`

Answer (score 0):

```
_str = 'C:\\\\Users\\\\U321103\\\\OneDrive - IBERDROLA S.A\\VARIABILIDAD CLIMATICA\\\\VORTEX\\\\WIND8\\349039.SPAIN.ESTE.CARRASCOSA.Power.csv'

# split by '\', than by '.', than slice. 
_str = _str.split('\\')[-1].split('.')[1:-1]
```

Output:

```
['SPAIN', 'ESTE', 'CARRASCOSA', 'Power']
```

If you want to join:

```
_str = '.'.join(_str)
```